# Model loses texture when appended?

Tags: append

I am trying to learn how to animate, and is currently working on a "casino themed video". However I am in general strugling a lot with colors & texture. Espeically understanding how it works with blenderrender & cycles render.

My problem right now, is that I found a free 3d model for a deck of cards that I wanna use. I have appended multiple objects before, and they usually keep their texture. However, these do not, can anyone see why?
I can see in the objects comments that no one else seem to have this problem. 
Thanks in advance. 
I have set a few pictures to show what I mean. (I have testet both blender render & cycles render)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/41ncW.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GswQs.png

Comment: And... where are the pictures?

Comment: Good question, I thought they were added, they should be as links now. :)

Comment: Check that the objects are set to draw mode 'texture' and not set to 'solid' in the properties panel. Also your first image shows a 3d view with Solid draw mode on and not Texture mode - but also check to see that the object has a texture in the material texture panel.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, just checked and it was solid, but changing it sadly didn't solve the problem. :)